# QGIS attribute default value in case of new or splitted feature

Tags: qgis, editing

I'd like to know if it's possible to put an expression for default values that is different in case of adding a new feature versus splitting an existing feature. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question, it had me try some differente options.
One which works is the following:

Access Layer `Properties` (by double-clicking the layer's name), then:

## 1 - Make sure there is an enforced unique field.

chec in the `Field` section.
In this case I used `fid`, which is the default

## 2 - Attribute Forms

Under `Attribute Forms`select the filed you want to update (in this example, I created a text field named `label`), and use an expression like this in the  `Default value` filed:

```
if(  "fid" = 'Autogenerate', 'I am brand new', 'I was split' )
```

[image]

## 3 - Save before splitting

I found that saving before splitting/editing is critical, otherwise the trick will not work.

So the workflow would be:

1. add the new feature(s)
2. save the layer
3. split/edit

[image]

Comment: Thank you. A test on the unique key id is something I'm doing indeed, but the suggested workflow is too involved to do each time for me. I've done a case test on the key id value and the field that I need to fill with default values, and it seems that I'm able to differentiate a new feature case from the new part in a split operation, but I've not very clear the use of attribute(attribute_name) or field name to access to the feature attribute stored values or input forms ones... I need still clarifying...